# Patchwork resulting in plots of different widths although having the same area

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, patchwork

I'm assembling eleven plots with patchwork. But, weirdly, the top right plot is narrower than the others despite having the same area defined in `plot_layout()`. Here is a reprex:

```
create_plot <- function(x=NA){
  tibble(name = sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace=T),
               value = sample(letters[6:10], 50, replace=T)
               ) %>% 
  count(name, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=n, fill=value))+
  geom_col(show.legend = F)
}

areas <- c(  #top left bottom right
  area(1,1,1,4),    
  area(1,5,1,8),
  area(1,9,1,12),
  area(2,2,2,5),
  area(2,8,2,11),
  area(3,2,3,5),
  area(3,8,3,11),
  area(4,2,4,5),
  area(4,8,4,11),
  area(5,2,5,5),
  area(5,8,5,11)
)

plot(areas)

map(1:11, create_plot) %>% 
wrap_plots()+guide_area()+
  plot_layout(design = areas)
```

And here is the result:

[image: result of the code]

All plots have the same width, except the top right one, which is narrower. I also tried using the grid string with the same result:

```
areas <- "
  AAAABBBBCCCC
  #DDDD##EEEE#
  #FFFF##GGGG#
  #HHHH##IIII#
  #JJJJ##KKKK#
"
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug, but it is the effect of where the right margin is. E.g. if you use `areas2 <- "
  AAAABBBBCCCCC
  #DDDD##EEEE##
  #FFFF##GGGG##
  #HHHH##IIII##
  #JJJJ##KKKK##
"` where you force plot C to have 1 extra column  and all the other lines an extra empty field the sizing looks correct.

Comment: Thank you. Adding this extra space, then the right top plot is a bit wider than the others. I will report the bug, will see.

Comment: Is this bug fixed?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't.