# Multiple ggplots in same plot window

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Below is my `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

x <- seq(0.01, .99, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(x, 2),
  y = c(qlogis(x), 2 * qlogis(x)),
  group = rep(c("a","b"),
  each = 100)
)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
wrap_plots(A = p1, B = p2, C = p4, design = "AABB\n#CC#")
```

With this I am getting below plot

[image]

As you can see, the first 2 plots do not appear to be of same size. I looks like 1st plot is taking more space than the 2nd plot. The 3rd plot also does not appear to be just in middle.

Is there any way to correct these inconsistencies?

Comment: Looks like this was recently asked in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576104/patchwork-resulting-in-plots-of-different-widths-although-having-the-same-area.  Currently an open issue in `patchwork`: https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/303

Comment: @JonSpring while I can wait until this bug fixed, is there any alternate approach for such arrangement of `ggplots`?

Comment: Approx slightly manual solution: `(p1 + p2) / (plot_spacer() + p3 + plot_spacer() + plot_layout(widths = c(1,2.5,1)))` but it will vary depending on the space that the vertical axis needs in `p3`.

Comment: How do you want `p3` centered? It looks like the midpoint of `p3` is midway between the plot areas of `p1` and `p2`, but maybe you are looking to align them another way?

Comment: `p3` does not appear to be in middle. I want to center it w.r.t. plot width